# Required field is not working in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

in my model i have email, password,new password and re-type new password property's are there.

```
[Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email: ")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public bool changePassword { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Old Password:*")]
    public string OldPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "New Password:*")]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Re-type Password:*")]
```

i put required to all controls. 
in my view i devide those controls like, Email in one form and remaining are another form. my problem is email validation is working in form form.

coming to another form validation is not working.

can any one suggest me to come out this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your cshtml file say layout try putting this

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")
```

this might work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are submitting to proper controller and using the **ModelState.IsValid**

```
// POST: /Orders/Create 
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] 
public ActionResult Create(Orders order) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        try {
        .....
```

Comment: i tried that one also, but it is not working, By using javascript i did it.